# Any issues with using Windows Authentication for SSIS/SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I work as a consultant for a client. Currently to develop my packages I use Windows Authentication and deploy the packages on the SQL Server (Integration Services Catalog). Once deployed I have the SQL Server Agent run these packages through jobs. It runs successfully without any issues so far.

My question is in the future when I am no longer at my client will this setup I have break due to my login being expired. I was under the impression that once I deployed to the server and run the packages through the SQL Server Agent it doesn't use my account at all!

Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your package protection level. Default is `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey`. This allows SSIS to seamlessly encrypt/decrypt things like database/ftp passwords based on your AD domain account. Other people at your client *should* be able to open up the package although the ability to decrypt sensitive data may be hindered.

What will happen is that when your account is removed, at least based on the experience of a former employer with 2005 was that the jobs will fail to decrypt the package and blow up. Even though they had no sensitive data in the connection string (no UID or PWD values), the connection string as a whole is encrypted and it was no joy. That's been 7 years so that might not be the case any more but I'd be unwilling to risk it.

My mechanism for mitigating this risk is to always set my packages as DontSaveSensitive and then use a sane configuration approach for handling these things. I prefer SQL Server table as a backing but XML can work fine.

Comment: My package protection level is saved as DontSaveSensitive. So with this protection level and deploying the packages on the Server and running them as the SQL Server Agent Service Account it shouldn't cause any issues right?

Comment: That's been my experience.